# QML - required custom property

Tags: qml

Is there any way to make a custom property required in QML? E.g., something like:

```
property required int numRows
```

I want to enforce that the user of the component passes a certain property, because the component will not work without it.

Comment: The `Qt` way would be for the component not to show and display a warning using `qWarning()` or show a warning inside the component itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, you can't. The most robust way is simply to give a valid default value to the property.

a workaround could be to give an invalid value (e.g -1) and check value in the Component.onCompleted slot of your item and show a console.log if property wasn't valid...

but prefer the first way, a component should always be usable with default values, for reusability goals!

Answer (score 9):

There is a required option was added in QT 5.15  qml: [qt doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#required-properties).
The syntax is the following:

```
required property <propertyType> <propertyName>
```

Thanks Marcin Orlowski for update

Comment: you forgot to mention that required property is relatively new feature of introduced in QT 5.15: https://www.qt.io/blog/new-qml-language-features-in-qt-5.15

Answer (score 0):

Qt trolls have told themselves that Component.onCompleted is not the preferred way to do most things, but a hack the had to implement.

The best possible is to use a declarative-style enabler, something like this would be ideal:

```
MyItem{
  property int myvalue: -1
  enabled: myvalue != -1  // Use other number if neccesary
}
```

This would work for enabling interactive elements, but more interesting stuff can be made like:

```
MyItem{
  property int myvalue: -1
  onMyvalueChanged:{
      enabled = true
      callMyInitFunction(something)
  }
}
```

That will trigger when the user changes the value, then you can call other functions or initializers. If you want to init only once, you can check if it's disabled.

```
MyItem{
  property int myvalue: -1
  onMyvalueChanged:{
      if (!enabled){
        enabled = true
        callMyInitFunction(something)
        return
      }
      // Stuff to do of already initialized
      callOtherStuff(otherThing)
  }
}
```

Finally, by reading the words you wrote "passes a certain property" it seems you might instead create a javascript function for the object and call it.

```
MyItem{
 property int _myprop: 0
 function launch(param1, param2, param3){
    _myprop = param3
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Then you would call it by launching it instead of creating it, this might work for a reusable Dialog, depends on your use case.

Of course there are several ways to do things depending on what you need.